# Call DisplayFormatAttribute's Logic from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In My MVC5 application, I have this DisplayFormat attribute set on a property of my model. It ensures that my double value 'TotalPrice' is always rendered with two decimal places on the screen (in a Razor page)

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")]
public Double? TotalPrice { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to call the same logic from within my Controller (C# code). So something like:

return DataFormatAttribute.ApplyFormattingTo(shoppingCart.TotalPrice);

That's obviously nowhere near correct but I hope it helps to clarify the question. I'm not really interested in the specific example of 2 decimal places, more how to apply an attribute's behaviour to a value by myself in C#.

I've downloaded the MVC5 source code, but it's all a bit too abstract for me to get my head around.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you intending to return the formatted value back to the view or to you database/storage ? I'm trying to understand the purpose.

Comment: Just editing my question to try and clarify. I need to do in my C# code, whatever it is that the MVC5 framework is doing for me when its rendering the value to 2 decimal places. Bear with me...

Comment: What are you actually wanting this for? You only need to format the value for display in a view (which is what your `DisplayFormatAttribute` does) Why do you need to _call the same logic from within my Controller_?

Comment: Because I have one method that returns the raw value e.g. 3.9 as a Json result of an ajax request, so it's not rendered as if it was a model value. I could render it to 3.90 myself before I send it back, but I was hoping to hook into the attribute's functionality. Then if I ever change the display logic, I only ever need to change it in one place. Also, I was interested in how the attributes actually work under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if its available OOB but it looks like you need to read the `Attribute` and apply your formatting. Write an extension method that will apply the formatting based on the `DisplayFormatAttribute` `DataFormatString` property.

I hope this sample gets you started, even if it's not an exact solution. This sample is tightly bound to `DisplayFormatAttribute` only

```
    public static string ApplyFormattingTo(this object myObject, string propertyName) 
    {
        var property = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);        
        var attriCheck = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute), false); 
        if(attriCheck.Any())
        {   
             return string.Format(((DisplayFormatAttribute)attriCheck.First()).DataFormatString,property.GetValue(myObject, null)); 
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Usage

```
Cart model= new Cart();
model.amount = 200.5099;    
var formattedString = pp.ApplyFormattingTo("amount");
```

Actual implementation varies according to your requirement. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help. Im afk at the mo but will post back when I can. Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Searching! This works perfectly. I know what I'm doing is probably not following best practices but it's really useful to be able to do this when needed. I'll post my actual code as another answer for completeness. And, I expect this approach can be used to hook into the functionality of any attributes, to avoid repeating code.

Answer (score 0):

@Searching provided the answer, so this is just my final code in case it helps others in the future. The **CartExtension** class provides extension methods for a class called **Cart**.

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public static class CartExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Apply the formatting defined by the DisplayFormatAttribute on one of the Cart object's properties
        /// programatically. Useful if the property is being rendered on screen, but not via the usual Html.DisplayFor
        /// method (e.g. via Javascript or some other method)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cart"></param>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ApplyFormattingTo(this Cart cart, string propertyName)
        {
            var property = cart.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            var attriCheck = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute), false);
            if (attriCheck.Any())
            {
                return string.Format(((DisplayFormatAttribute)attriCheck.First()).DataFormatString, property.GetValue(cart, null));
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used to return the value preformatted for the screen e.g. in a Controller method:

```
return Json(cart.ApplyFormattingTo("TotalPrice"));
```